# Error creating foreign key in Firebird DB

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have 2 tables: commerciaux and production. I want to create a Foreign key in production linked to the table commerciaux.

```
ALTER TABLE PRODUCTION
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTION_1
FOREIGN KEY (NOM_COMMERCIAL)
REFERENCES COMMERCIAUX(NOM_COMMERCIAL)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

When I commit I got the error:

```
This operation is not defined for system tables.
unsuccessful metadata update.
could not find UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint in table COMMERCIAUX with specified columns.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: I've removed the Delphi-related tags, as your question has nothing to do with Delphi at all. Please use only tags that are applicable to the question you're asking. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should be used properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The requirement is written right in the error message

> could not find UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint in table COMMERCIAUX with specified columns.

You have to create this or that constraint on the table `COMMERCIAUX`, so that the column `COMMERCIAUX(NOM_COMMERCIAL)` would get an unique index.

See chapter [5.4.1.7.3 The UNIQUE Constraint](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-constraints-uq)

Also read there another chapter:

> **5.4.1.7.4 FOREIGN KEY**
> A Foreign Key ensures that the participating column(s) can contain only values that also exist in the referenced column(s) in the master table. These referenced columns are often called **target columns. They must be the primary key or a unique key in the target table.** They need not have a NOT NULL constraint defined on them although, if they are the primary key, they will, of course, have that constraint.

Without having unique index Firebird can not give you warranties that values in "target columns" are unique. Then, without the warranty of those values being unique Firebird can not materialize many-to-one relationship, that Foreign Key is.

Comment: The Problem is that the Field COMMERCIAUX(NOM_COMMERCIAL) is not unique it is a Field for names
so many person can has the same name : like jhon

Comment: @MrSiMo then it can not be foreign key, by definition of FK - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key and https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/what-is-a-foreign-key/ and SQL standard (but it is commercial book, not available for free)  |||  what is you **real** problem then?  https://xyproblem.info ||| are you trying to create a `CHECK CONSTRAINT` with `EXISTS` predicate inside?  ||| and why at all have a 'link' from `production` table to random everyone's and noone's name? Don't you have to link that FK to COMMERCIAUX's PK instead of non-unique `NOM_COMMERCIAL` ???